# Are Google Map polygons indexed / how do I refer to their index?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, polygon

Below is an example of 3 polygons I'm adding to a map.  I intend to include click events to each; however, I would like to output some element of each polygon that I can refer to and relate to other data such as description, images, etc.  The output could be the short title (variable names) given to each shape- here e609, c815, and c840- or an index number- ideally the number given in the comment before each polygon.

Are polygons given index numbers given on the order they enter the map?  If so, how do I refer to this number as to pass it to another function?  Alternatively, how could I pass along the short titles?

```
//0
var e609;
var e609_c = [
    //Latlng, cut for space.
];
e609 = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: e609_c,
    strokeOpacity: 0,
    fillColor: "#B1509E",
    fillOpacity: .4
});
e609.setMap(map);

//1
var c815;
var c815_c = [
    //Latlng, cut for space.
];
c815 = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: c815_c,
    strokeOpacity: 0,
    fillColor: "#B1509E",
    fillOpacity: .4
});
c815.setMap(map);

//2
var c840;
var c840_c = [
    //Latlng, cut for space.
];
c840 = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: c840_c,
    strokeOpacity: 0,
    fillColor: "#B1509E",
    fillOpacity: .4
});
c840.setMap(map);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may include custom fields to describe the polygon inside the object creation, for example, I added description and shortTitle. I don't know of a direct way of getting the variable name, so it is merely repeated. The polygons should be indexed internally though I'm not sure how to access that information. With the variable name you assign the new polygon, you can manipulate it.

```
e609 = new google.maps.Polygon({
    description: "Polygon named e609",
    shortTitle: "e609",
    paths: e609_c,
    strokeOpacity: 0,
    fillColor: "#B1509E",
    fillOpacity: .8
});
```

When adding a click listener, you need to refer to it by its variable name (e609), or what I would do, make an array of polygons, say `var myPolygons = []` and `push` e609 into this array. Then you can address it as `myPolygons[0]`. Or you can use an object to hold polygons by their short titles, for example, `myPolygons['e609']`.

Anyway, below is how you may use the fields created in the polygon definition.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(e609, 'click', function(event) {
  alert("Clicked on " + this.description + " short title " + this.shortTitle);
});
```

Comment: Ah, this is perfect.  Actually, it's likely better than perfect as, if I can place the other information into this as well using the custom fields, it'll simplify everything.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The way I did it was to use [TAFFY.JS](http://taffydb.com/).

When creating the poly, I passed a unique index number as a custom parameter called "indexID"

```
var returnObj = new google.maps.Polygon({
             paths: [arcPts],
             strokeColor: beamColor,
             strokeOpacity: 0.5,
             strokeWeight: 3,
             fillColor: fillColor,
             fillOpacity: 0.1,
             map: map,
             indexID: i
    });
```

then I added it to a TAFFY database that I named "toggle" (I'm using the function to show/hide poly's)

```
google.maps.event.addListener(returnObj, 'rightclick', function (event) {
  // add to make visible db
  toggle.insert({
    "indexID":i,
    "obj":returnObj
  });
});
```

now, I'm able to reference the map object by its ID and do something with it

```
var ret=toggle({"indexID":5}).get();    
ret[0].obj.setVisible(true);
```